# I'm trying to run a Debian 11 VM on my CentOS 7 Home Server, but get hit by this issue with virt-install

Tags: linux, centos, python, qemu, pip

See below, the issue im having when trying to run virt-install on its own. Same issue when I try with all the config I plan to use:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:104: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.9) or chardet (2.2.1)/charset_normalizer (None) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 29, in <module>
    import virtinst
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    from virtinst.distroinstaller import DistroInstaller
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import urlfetcher
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/urlfetcher.py", line 33, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/certs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from certifi import where
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import contents, where
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/core.py", line 17
    def where() -> str:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also see the main issue highlighted `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:104: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.9) or chardet (2.2.1)/charset_normalizer (None) doesn't match a supported version!`

After searching it up, I see a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202238/python-pip-requestsdependencywarning-urllib3-1-9-1-or-chardet-2-3-0-doe

Following this doesn't work either as pip just doesn't seem to want to work:

```
pip install --upgrade urllib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2566, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2260, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/certs.py", line 17, in <module>
    from certifi import where
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import contents, where
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/core.py", line 17
    def where() -> str:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm just completely stumped and don't know how to progress.

My main goal is to run this software - https://github.com/ab77/netflix-proxy even though I only have a CentOS 7 server set up, and I do not plan to reinstall the machine with Debian, unless someone has a better solution, I still plan to continue with emulation.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem today.
My solution was to delete the directory `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi`.
Later I have installed the version 2020.4.5.1 with pip
`pip install certifi==2020.4.5.1`

Comment: Tried these steps and got the following: [PasteBin Link](https://pastebin.com/xBYz0GuE)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is very new, I found this is caused by Tornado, inside of tornado-4.4.2.tar.gz, I found this document saying:
*Tornado now depends on the `certifi <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi>`_
package instead of bundling its own copy of the Mozilla CA list. This will
be installed automatically when using `pip` or `easy_install`.*

and going to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi,it is showing the latest version: **certifi 2022.5.18.1**
I am using docker, so in my Dockerfile, After installation of Tornado, I used the suggestion by cordigliere ( Thank you),

RUN rm -r /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi

RUN pip install certifi==2020.4.5.1

it is working for me.

hopefully this will be fix in next certifi

Comment: Tried these steps and got the following: [PasteBin Link](https://pastebin.com/xBYz0GuE)